# Set custom socket implementation in HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, sockets, networking, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

Looking for java networking experts here :)

The team that I'm part of is developing a solution which consists of server part and a small client API (and api-impl) bundle that our customers must deploy and use in order to make http requests to the server part.

One of our customers who uses the API is asking us to provide him with a new method for setting a custom Socket implementation, so that the actual http communication with the server part can go through his Socket. Until now, we used HttpsUrlConnection to connect to the server part. The question is - is it possible to somehow supply the HttpsUrlConnection with a custom socket implementation instead of the default one? What are the alternatives? Is Apache HttpClient able to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setSSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory)) an [SSLSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) on an HttpsUrlConnection. This is only possible with ssl and not with the "plain" HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: How am I supposed to set this connection factory before opening the actual connection with .openConnection()? Setting a default connection factory is not an option since this will interfere with all the others outgoing http connections of the software

Comment: The "openConnection" method is a bit misleading. It does not actually establish the connection. That can occur at the earliest when you start writing content to the request body (but even then only if you set chunked or fixed length streaming mode). By default the actual connection occurs when you ask for something about the response (such as the InputStream or response code).

Comment: Yep, thank you very much! This is exactly what I was hoping for

Answer (score 0):

One can fully customize the way Apache HttpClient instantiates sockets and connects them to a remote endpoint by using `ConnectionSocketFactory`. [This example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.3.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteSOCKS.java) for instance demonstrates how connect to an external host via a SOCKS proxy